# How to determine the magnitude and direction of a force

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am trying to understand how the solution got the degree of 95, I've done a similar problem with this before, but I had to add the two degrees, when I add the two degrees in this problem I get 75, and not 95.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The red line is the 800lbs, while the blue ones are the 500.

[image]

The vector addition parallelogram rule is presented by the green arrow (this is the resultant force.

For the cosine law, you need to use the angle (a) opposite to the green side (on the red blue, green triangle. That angle is supplementary to the angle 50 + 35 = 85, so a= 180-85 =95

Answer (score 2):

Draw the vector forces with the arrow of the first vector touching the tail of the second, then draw a horizontal reference line passing the point. Find the unknown angle using the property that the sum of the angles must be added up to 180 degrees.

[image]